# python error typeerror: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I have got an error when I try this:

```
if int(pos_X) == 375:
   data = prog_id
   print data
   index_get = int(prog_index)

   for i in index_get:
      #test = data[i]
      print i
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
for index in index_get:
```

Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Here is the output for the `index_get`:

```
18:17:59 T:5172  NOTICE: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
18:17:59 T:5172  NOTICE: [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Here is the code:

```
program_index_ = list()

for elem in program_button:
    progId.append(elem.getId())
    posX.append(elem.getX())
    posY.append(elem.getY())
progId = map(str, progId)
posX = map(str, posX)
posY = map(str, posY)

for channel in channels:
    if stop_date is not None:
        if start_time <> current_time < stop_time:
            if current_program_length >= 30:
                program_index = self.program_index
                self.program_remaining = True
            program_index_.append(program_index)
        self.program_index += 1

        if self.program_index == 7:
           program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
           progId = list()
           posX = list()
           posY = list()

           for elem in program_button:
               progId.append(elem.getId())
               posX.append(elem.getX())
               posY.append(elem.getY())
           progId = map(str, progId)
           posX = map(str, posX)
           posY = map(str, posY)

           for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_index in izip_longest(posX, posY, progId, program_index_, fillvalue=''):

               data = prog_id
               print data
               index_get = int(prog_index)

               for i in index_get:
                   #test = data[i]
                   print i
```

I am trying to get the string from the array using the index. The type for the `index_get` is a int.

Can you please tell me how to fix the error?

Comment: What would you expect `for i in 5` to do?

Comment: @birryree yep that is correct. I want to iterate through the first index_get items in a list. If I have one or more items in a list then I want to output them. How i can do that?

Comment: @ChadS. What I expect `for i` in 5 to do is to get the first index_get items in a list to output them. If I have one or more items in a list then I want to output them. How i can do that?

Comment: `for item in data[:index_get]` is what you want. Slice the list into just the items you want.

Comment: Sorry I think I want the slice the list into the items. I have got the error when you gave me the code so here is the error `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Comment: If you want to iterate over the first `index_get` items, then you'd want to do what Chad suggests. If you want to just print the slice out: `print data[:index_get]` would work. I don't know how Chad's code would break if you already did `index_get = int(prog_index)`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs why are you posting the link? it wont help me to solve the problem unless you post the code

Comment: @Danny I'm posting the link because I think it would be more of a benefit to you if you first learned how for loops and slicing work instead of attempting to copy-paste code that people write for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting your list as an int. An int is not iterable.

Change `for i in index_get:` to `for i in prog_index:`

If you are worried that `i` is not always an int, but a str instead, cast it within the loop.

```
for i in index_get:
    test = data[int(i)]
    print int(i)
```

Comment: I have changed from this `for i in index_get:` to `for i in prog_index:` now I am getting this `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Any idea?

Comment: My mistake. You don't need the nested loop at all. iziplongest already assigns the value of program_index_ at the index of the iteration of the loop. Therefore, the value you are trying to get in i is simply prog_index. Remove `for i in prog_index:' altogether and just use prog_index in place of i.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost python doesn't have a native array data structure, it has lists. Arrays imply a data structure of fixed length, such as you'd find in Java or C. Lists imply a data structure of variable length such as the one you are using here.

There are many ways to get the string from the LIST.

```
for str in prog_index:
    print str

for i in range(len(prog_index)):
    print prog_index[i]

for i in enumerate(prog_index):
    print prog_index[i]

for i, j in enumerate(prog_index):    #just for fun
    print i, j

for i in xrange(len(lst)):            #python3 we use xrange instead of range
    print i
```

And there are many more ways. Make use of the python shell to interactively fiddle with these problems while they are small. You will save the desk a few head dents when things get harder later.